# RuntimeError: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number

Tags: python, java, apache-spark, pyspark

When I initiate pyspark on pycharm / jupyter notebook, I just keep getting this error:

> RuntimeError: Java gateway process exited before sending its port
> number

I did the following:

1. pip installed pyspark,
2. installed java 8, added environment variables,
3. tested java on cmd, input `java`, `java -version`, `javac`, all okay
4. in my code, I added `os.environ['JAVA_HOME'] = 'D:\java'`, not working
5. added `os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = "--master local"` not working

Pretty sure java 8 was set properly, however just kept getting this error.

please help